# Adding student in only specific class list using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem in viewing only a class list that I choose and add student but when I select other class it will also appear/view that I select in previous class

here I select the class that I select
[image]

Here is the class page that I select and then I add student
[image]

but when I choose another class it will also appear the student
[image][image]

here is my controller:

```
 public function viewspecificclass($id)
{
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
 $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
 $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
 $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
 $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
       $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

       $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
       $row=$this->model_adminlogin->getonerowclass($id);
       $data['r']=$row;
       $data['classid'] = $id;

   $this->load->view('individualviewclass',$data);
    } else{
        redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
    }
    if((!isset($session_data) || $session_data !=TRUE)) {

        redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
    }


}

    public function addstudentnow($classid, $studentid){

           $data= array(

                'ClassId'=>$classid,
               'Id'=> $studentid
        );
          $this->db->insert('enroll',$data);

         $this->session->set_flashdata('category_success', 'Successfully Add!');
         redirect('enrollment/viewspecificclass ');
```

}

here is my model:

```html
  function statusofenrollment(){
        
        
        $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('studentinformation');
 $this->db->join('statusofenrollment', 'statusofenrollment.Id = studentinformation.Id', 'left');
 
  
    

  
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
    }
     function studentinclasslist(){
        
        
        $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('statusofenrollment');
 $this->db->join('studentinformation', 'studentinformation.Id = statusofenrollment.Id', 'right');
  $this->db->join('enroll', 'enroll.Id = studentinformation.Id', 'right');
   
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
    }
```

here is the view:

```
        <div class="z table-responsive">

          <table class=" table table-striped ">

                 <thead>
                         <tr>

                             <th class="text-center">LRN</th>
                               <th class="text-center">First name</th>
                               <th class="text-center"> Middle name</th>
                               <th class="text-center">Last name</th>
                                 <th class="text-center">Gender</th>
                                   <th class="text-center">Status of Enrollment</th>
                           <th class="text-center"> </th>

                       </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <?php


                foreach($this->model_adminlogin->studentinclasslist() as $row){

                        ?>





      <tr>


              <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Idnumber ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Lastname ?></td>
                <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Sex ?></td>
                <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Statusofenrollment ?></td>

                         <td class="text-capitalize text-center">

                         </td>

     </tr>


              <?php
          }




                     ?>
          </table>
      </div>







       <div id="myModalpick" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Student Status</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="z table-responsive">

          <table class=" table table-striped ">

                 <thead>
                         <tr>

                             <th class="text-center">LRN</th>
                               <th class="text-center">First name</th>
                               <th class="text-center"> Middle name</th>
                               <th class="text-center">Last name</th>
                                 <th class="text-center">Gender</th>
                                   <th class="text-center">Status of Enrollment</th>
                           <th class="text-center"> </th>

                       </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <?php


                foreach($this->model_adminlogin->statusofenrollment() as $row){

                        ?>





      <tr>


              <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Idnumber ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Lastname ?></td>
                <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Sex ?></td>
                <td class="text-capitalize text-center"><?php echo $row->Statusofenrollment ?></td>

                         <td class="text-capitalize text-center">
                             <a href="<?php echo site_url('enrollment/addstudentnow/'.$classid. '/'.$row->Idnumber ) ?>" class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" role="button"> Add To Class List </a>

                         </td>

     </tr>


              <?php
          }




                     ?>
          </table>
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Ok</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i really tried hard to understand whats going on, but since you use models in your views its really hard to follow your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of the fact that your code is totally unorganized it makes hard to help you - but i'll give it a shot

first of all in your models Function studenClassList you've to pass an id from the specific class because other wise you'll get on any request the students of all of your classes - change your model like this

```
function studentinclasslist($classId){

    $query = $this->db
        ->select('studentinformation.*')
        ->from('statusofenrollment')
        ->join('studentinformation', 'studentinformation.Id = statusofenrollment.Id', 'right')
        ->join('enroll', 'enroll.Id = studentinformation.Id', 'right')
        ->where("class.Id",$classId)
        ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

be aware that you have to change in the where construct the actual class.Id field because i wasn't able to see where it is

and after that in your view simply pass the ID to your model function

```
foreach($this->model_adminlogin->studentinclasslist($classId) as $row){
```

but in any case i must say, in my opinion it isn't a good idea in CI to use a model in your view because the controller should pass the prepared model data to the view